# Javascript not working!! cannot redirect to java page

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function editRecord(id) {
            url="EditRecord";
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8084/BookStore/" +url+ "?id" + id;
            return false;
        }
</script>



<tr>
                    <% String s = (String) itr.next();%>
                    <td> <%=s%> </td>
                    <td> <%=itr.next()%> </td>
                    <td> <%=itr.next()%> </td>
                    <td> <%=itr.next()%> </td>
                    <td> <%=itr.next()%> </td>
                    <td><input class="dr-input" type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" onclick="editRecord(<%=s%>)"></td>
                    <td><input class="dr-input" type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" onclick="deleteRecord(<%=s%>);"></td>
                        <% }%>
                </tr>
```

what I want is, when i click the button(Edit) it should redirect to a servlet page(EditRecord.java).
The Above code is in jsp. the Button doesnt redirect to the specified page. what's wrong with the code?
Is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: Why not change it to a link instead? Can you add cosole.log inside your function, to see if it's executed?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<script>` and `<tr>` cannot be siblings. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: If your JavaScript doesn't work, then look at your JavaScript, not at the JSP that generates it. Also look at your JS console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: cant change to link because I want "id" that i have passed through<%=s%>.

Comment: #Quentin I am getting the following error: Error: Misplaced non-space characters insided a table.
From line 34, column 26; to line 39, column 24
     </tr>↩                    <% Iterator itr; ↩                     List data = (List) request.getAttribute("BooksData");↩                        for (itr = data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {↩                    %>↩                    <tr>↩